# Binding IIS to POP3 Port

Tags: asp.net, iis, pop3

I want to bind IIS hosted web site to POP3 port 110. It actually binds but returns nothing when called from web browser (Chrome says: "This webpage is not available").
There is no process listening to port 110 when I look with `netstat -ab`, otherwise IIS couldn't bind it.

How can I force IIS to serve on reserved port like this? (IIS 8.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable outgoing traffic in your firewall on port 110.

hth,
dave

Comment: I try to access it from localhost which doesn't pass over firewall, not working. I also tried with disabled the firewall same result. When I change the port to 112 it works. Just 110th port is causing the problem.